# InvalidParameterException when running "convox ps"

Tags: convox

Suddenly getting a **InvalidParameterException** when running `convox ps`:

`InvalidParameterException: Invalid identifier: Identifier is for cluster AAAAAAA. Your cluster is BBBBBBB. status code: 400`

We haven't changed anything with the Convox configuration recently, so unsure why this would suddenly start happening.

Has anyone encountered this before, or can suggest a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried doing a rack update? There was a new release last week to address some changes AWS made to ECS API call validations - https://github.com/convox/rack/releases/tag/20211012210133

`convox rack update -r rackname 20211012210133`

As always, I would recommend testing in QA/staging before pushing to prod.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.